# Updating dynamic QGridLayout - Python PyQt

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, qscrollarea, qgridlayout

I recently started studying Python and now I'm making a software with a GUI using PyQt Libraries.

Here's my problem:
I create a Scrollarea, I put in this scrollarea a widget which contains a QGridLayout.

```
    sa = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    sa_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.sa_grid.setSizeConstraint(QtGui.QLayout.SetMinAndMaxSize)
    sa_widget.setLayout(self.sa_grid)
    sa.setWidgetResizable(True)
    sa.setWidget(sa_widget)
```

Then I add 10 QLabel (this is just an example of course, in this example I'm using a QGridLayout just like a Vertical Layout):

```
    i = 0
    while i<100:
        i = i +1
        add = QtGui.QLabel("Row %i" % i)
        self.sa_grid.addWidget(add)
```

Then I create a button that calls the function "function_name", I want that this function deletes a row, so  far this is what I've written:

```
    tmp = QtGui.QWidget()
    tmp = self.sa_grid.itemAt(0)
    self.sa_grid.removeItem(tmp)
```

It deletes the first row and every x row of the gridlayout becomes row x-1, however, it doesn't delete the text "Row 1" so I see "Row 0" and "Row 1" on the same row.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot in advance, Davide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing an item from a layout does not delete it. The item will just become a free-floating object with no associated layout.

If you want to get rid of the object completely, explicitly delete it:

```
def deleteGridWidget(self, index):
    item = self.sa_grid.itemAt(index)
    if item is not None:
        widget = item.widget()
        if widget is not None:
            self.sa_grid.removeWidget(widget)
            widget.deleteLater()
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! I wasted so much time looking for an answer and now I got it. Could you suggest me some great Python/PyQt tutorial, please? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @TheTux94. The [PyQt Wiki](http://www.diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/StartPage?action=show&redirect=FrontPage) is not a bad place to start. Not all the material is up to date (some of it relates to PyQt3 rather than PyQt4), but if you dig around you should find lots of useful stuff.